# How to connect to Elasticsearch with Docker Compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I connect from my web app to an Elasticsearch instance using the Java API:

```java
static Optional<Client> getClient(String hostName, int port) {
  return getHost(hostName).map(host -> TransportClient.builder().build()
      .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port))
  );
}

static Optional<InetAddress> getHost(String hostName) {
  InetAddress host = null;
  try {
    host = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    LOG.warn("Could not get host: {}", hostName, e);
  }
  return Optional.ofNullable(host);
}
```

Before switching to [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), I started Elasticsearch using

```
docker run --net=my-network --name=myDb elasticsearch
```

and my web app using

```
docker run --net=my-network -p 8080:4567 me/myapp
```

and sure enough, I could connect to the database using `getClient("myDb", 9300)`.

But now that I've switched to Docker Compose, I don't know how to connect to Elasticsearch. This is my current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  my-app:
    image: me/myapp
    ports:
      - "8080:4567"
    networks:
      - my-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Understandably, this results in an `UnknownHostException` since I haven't set the hostname of my Elasticsearch instance in the `docker-compose.yml`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set an [`alias`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases):

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    networks:
      my-network:
        aliases:
          - myDb
```

Now I can connect to `myDb` on port 9300 when calling `getClient("myDb", 9300)` shown in the question.